# How to set the Report path in App.path VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, path, crystal-reports

Can anyone know how to set the Crystal Report path as App.path. Because in my project, the report path in **LocalDisk(D:)**. I copy the debug folder to another computer with only one **LocalDisk(C:)**. It display error. So i need the reports in app path. How i perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Its ok with above code..........